# Python requests in Docker Compose containers

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, python-requests

## Problem

- I have a 2-container `docker-compose.yml` file.
- One of the containers is a small [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) app.
- The other is just trying to hit the API using Python's `requests` package.

**I can access the app container from outside with the exact same code as is in the Python package trying to hit it, and it works**, but it will not work within the package.

## `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  read-api:
    build:
      context: ./read-api
    depends_on:
      - "toy-api"
    networks:
      - ds-net
  toy-api:
    build:
      context: ./api
    networks:
      - ds-net
    ports:
      - "80:80"
networks:
  ds-net:
```

## Relevant `requests` code

```py
from requests import Session

def post_to_api(session, raw_input, path):
    print(f"The script is sending: {raw_input}")
    print(f"The script is sending it to: {path}")
    response = session.post(path, json={"payload": raw_input})
    print(f"The script received: {response.text}")

def get_from_api(session, path):
    print(f"The datalake script is trying to GET from: {path}")
    response = session.get(path)
    print(f"The datalake script received: {response.text}")

session = Session()
session.trust_env = False ### I got that from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50326101/534238
get_from_api(session, path="http://localhost/test")
post_to_api(session, "this is a test", path="http://localhost/raw")
```

## Running It REPL-Style

If I create an interactive session and run those exact commands above in the `requests` code portion, it works:

```py
>>> get_from_api(session, path="http://localhost/test")
The script is trying to GET from: http://localhost/test
The script received: {"payload":"Yes, you reached here..."}
>>> post_to_api(session, "this is a test", path="http://localhost/raw")
The script is sending: this is a test
The script is sending it to: http://localhost/raw
The script received: {"payload":"received `raw_input`: this is a test"}
```

To be clear: the API code is still being run as a container, and that container was *still* created with the `docker-compose.yml` file.  (In other words, the API container is working properly, when accessed from the host.)

## Running Within Container

Doing the same thing within the container, I get the following (fairly long) errors:

```py
read-api_1    | The script is trying to GET from: http://localhost/test
read-api_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
read-api_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
read-api_1    |     conn = connection.create_connection(
read-api_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
read-api_1    |     raise err
read-api_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
read-api_1    |     sock.connect(sa)
read-api_1    | ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
read-api_1    | 
read-api_1    | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
.
.
.
read-api_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
read-api_1    |   File "access_api.py", line 99, in <module>
read-api_1    |     get_from_api(session, path="http://localhost/test")
read-api_1    |   File "access_datalake.py", line 86, in get_from_api
read-api_1    |     response = session.get(path)
read-api_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
read-api_1    |     return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
read-api_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
read-api_1    |     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
read-api_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
read-api_1    |     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
read-api_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
read-api_1    |     raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
read-api_1    | requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /test (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ffa9c69b3a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
ai_poc_work_read-api_1 exited with code 1
```

## Attempts to Solve

I thought it was with how the host identified itself within the container group, or whether that origin could be accessed, so I have already tried to change the following, with no success:

- Instead of using `localhost` as the host, I used `read-api`.

  - Actually, I started with `read-api`, and had no luck, but once using `localhost`, I could at least use REPL on the host machine, as shown above.
  - I also tried `0.0.0.0`, no luck.  (I did not expect that to fix it.)
- I have changed what CORS `ORIGINS` are allowed in the API, including all of the possible paths for the container that is trying to read, and just using `"*"` to flag all CORS origins.  No luck.

---

What am I doing wrong?  It seems the problem must be with the containers, or maybe how `requests` interacts with containers, but I cannot figure out what.

Here are some relevant GitHub issues or SO answers I found, but none solved it:

- [GitHub issue: Docker Compose problems with `requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/3948)
- [GitHub issue: Solving high latency `requests` in Docker containers](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/961)
- [SO problem: containers communicating with `requests`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040023/containers-communication-with-python-requests)

Comment: Did you try `get_from_api(session, path="http://read-api/test")` ?

Comment: You might read through [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation; that discusses what host names will be available to you.  `localhost` in Docker is usually "this container", not another container or the containing host or VM.

Comment: @GonzaloHernandez Yes, that is what I meant when I originally wrote "I started with `ds-net`, that was a typo that I have now fixed.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for the input, but I am not sure you understood what I wrote.  In fact, the reason why `localhost` *did* work was because I was mapping ports from the container to the host.  But as I wrote, I tried `localhost`, I tried `read-api` (OP had a typo explaining that, which I have now fixed), and I even tried `ds-net`, which I knew should not work, but I tried anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the Docker network, applications must be accessed with the service names defined in the `docker-compose.yml`.

If you're trying to access the `toy-api` service, use

```
get_from_api(session, path="http://toy-api/test")
```

You can access the application via `http://localhost/test` on your host machine because Docker exposes the application to the host machine. However, loosely speaking, within the Docker network, `localhost` does not refer to the host's `localhost` but only to the container's `localhost`. And in the case of the `read-api` service, there is no application listening to `http://localhost/test`.