# Clarity on Docker Container IP addresses for API requests

Tags: python, docker

I want to be able to connect to a third-party .NET API I am running as a docker image within a container. When I connect to the ip address and port on my browser it works though when I try and run a get request in python it does not. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

The Django python application is an image within the container using 0.0.0.0:8000.

This is the docker-compose.yml file for a .NET image I am running from within a container:

```
mt4rest:
    image: mt4rest:latest
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:5000:80"
```

Here are the ports as per docker inspect

```
  "Ports": {
                "443/tcp": null,
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "5000"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

When I run

```
http://0.0.0.0:5000/Ping
```

or

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/Ping
```

in my browser, I get OK though when I run the same endpoints in Python:

```
response = requests.get('http://0.0.0.0:5000/Ping')
```

or

```
response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/Ping')
```

I receive the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000):
Max retries exceeded with url: /Ping (Caused by
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fe7aa5af640>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

or

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /Ping (Caused by 
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f6322e2b640>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

I understand this to mean that the address for the request is not found.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Do you run Python from your host machine or from a Docker container ?

Comment: I am running a django docker image on 0.0.0.0:8000 and connecting to it successfully from a vue.js docker image using http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: I was not running vue.js from within a container - that is why it was connecting to 127.0.0.1:8000. Thanks to the accepted answer and the answer I posted I now understand how docker containers connect to localhost. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets call your host as HOST_BASE.
You are having two containers, one is exposing 5000 on host. Its HOST_BASE:5000.
Other is your python-app container.

Now, you are running another python-app in container on host `HOST_BASE`. And try to hit: `http://0.0.0.0:5000`, which is not accessible. Note: its `0.0.0.0` is localhost of the container itself.

You want to connect to `HOST_BASE:5000`, which is not `localhost` or `0.0.0.0`
You need to configure networking between your two containers. Or, for simplicity, use `--network host` while running both of your container.

Hope that helps.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a special IPv4 address that means "all interfaces"; 127.0.0.1 is the (context-specific) localhost address.  It doesn't usually make sense to make outbound connections to 0.0.0.0.  Disabling Docker's networking stack as you suggest in the last sentence isn't usually the correct solution; it works in some cases but you lose the ability to selectively publish ports or connect between containers by name.

Comment: --network=host is suggested for testing. And, its not for production usage.

Answer (score 0):

There is an acceptable answer for this question on stackoverflow which solves the problem:

[Python requests in Docker Compose containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64558200/python-requests-in-docker-compose-containers)